# Validate DI container at startup

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

I'd like to validate my DI container (aka check if I haven't forgotten to add a DI registration in my Startup class) at the very start of the application. Meaning, once all the services are added, I'd like to try and resolve each one of them so that the application throws an exception if I forgot one.

Naturally, I'd like to do this only in DEBUG mode. For the default NET Core DI container, I can iterate through services and try to resolve them all (as in the case below), but how do I do that through Autofac (preferrably in `ConfigureContainer`)?

```cs
#if DEBUG
    var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    foreach (var item in services)
    {
        _ = sp.GetRequiredService(item.ServiceType);
    }
#endif
```

Comment: Have you considered doing this as an unit test instead?

Comment: Come to think, I wouldn't mind doing it via unit testing. Although, I wouldn't like to mock it in the unit test method, since that would require me to mock every single interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autofac does not offer container registration validation [and has no plans to do so in the near future.](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/853) The issue I linked there explains why, but the long and the short of it is - since *so many* things can come from lambdas and dynamic code, there's too much that *can't* be validated. It seemed like the false positives or the "we validated 50% of the container but not the other 50% because it's dynamic" would give people a false sense of security, or, more likely, just make people angry that the results weren't correct. "My container validated but this thing failed! Autofac sucks!"

On the other hand, [Autofac 6.0 introduced a robust diagnostics mechanism](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/debugging.html) for troubleshooting and tracing issues. If you encounter issues, this can make it easier to figure out why.